# Bash function to search and cd based on filename

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a bash function to place in `.bashrc`.

This is along the lines of what I was thinking...

```
FindGO () 
{
alias go=cd $(find -name $1 | egrep -o ".+\/"); #finds file and chops of name at end for cd to work
echo "file directory containing $1 now aliased to go"; 
}
```

I would like some help in getting this to work (+ an error message if there is no file found).

**Update:**
I will leave this as is as it helped me at the time. But if anyone wants something to do this for real please consider [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases really suck. What you could do is define a function inside your `FindGO` function. And that sounds so cool:

```
FindGO () {
    local qfound
    local found=$(find -name "$1" -printf '%h' -quit)
    if [[ -z $found ]]; then
        echo "Oh dear, I couldn't find \`$1' anywhere... and I really looked everywhere."
        return 1
    fi
    printf -v qfound '%q' "$found"
    eval "go() { cd \"$(pwd)\"/$qfound; }"
    echo "Will change directory to the one containing \`$1' (namely \`$found') with the function go."
}
```

I know, `eval` is evil, but it's used with safely quoted `$qfound` variable.

- Using `find` with `-printf '%h'` that will only output the dir part of the file (so that your `grep` becomes useless).
- Using the `-quit` switch, so that `find` quits immediately after the first found file. That will speed things up a lot! You could adapt this if you want something special to happen when there are multiple found files (but beware on how you're going to get `find`'s output so that it works with any files with any funny symbols in their names).
- Then quoting the `found` dir with `printf` so that I can safely `eval` to define the `go` function.
- The target dir is computed at `FindGO`'s execution time, so as to not call another `find` each time you want to `go` (I believe that's a cool feature... if you don't, let me know we can change that). That's the reason for the `eval`. It's a very important part of this script. Actually that's why the explanation of this part is buried here in the middle of a boring list.
- I believe it is 100% safe regarding any funny symbols in filenames!
- <strike>A quick question to the OP: why use `find` and not `locate`?</strike> *see comments*.

Enjoy!

---

**Edit.** Dumb me, of course this fails when, e.g., `mkdir $'\n'; touch $'\n/lalala'`. Here's the cure: use bash's `printf '%q'` from within find:

```
FindGO () {
    local qfound=$(find -name "$1" -exec bash -c 'printf "%q" "$1"' _ {} \; -quit)
    if [[ -z $qfound ]]; then
        echo "Oh dear, I couldn't find \`$1' anywhere... and I really looked everywhere."
        return 1
    fi
    eval "go() { cd \"$(pwd)\"/$qfound; }"
    echo "Will change directory to the one containing \`$1' (namely \`$qfound') with the function go."
}
```

---

**Edit2.** I swear that the guy who wrote the two previous versions is profoundly idiotic. Because here's *the* solution. If you read (and understood) up to here, you've probably learned a few interesting stuff. Here's so more:

```
FindGO () {
    local qfound=$(find -name "$1" -execdir bash -c 'printf "%q" "$PWD"' {} \; -quit);
    if [[ -z $qfound ]]; then
        echo "Oh dear, I couldn't find \`$1' anywhere... and I really looked everywhere.";
        return 1;
    fi;
    eval "go() { cd $qfound; }";
    echo "Will change directory to the one containing \`$1' (namely \`$qfound') with the function go.";
}
```

As you can see, the solution is absolutely obvious, sane, cristal clear, not convoluted, and elegant. As it should always be:

- Use `find` with the `-execdir` flag, and ask bash to nicely `printf '%q'` its `$PWD` (notice: I'm asking for the *variable* `$PWD`, not the output of the command `pwd`, as this would fail miserably if a directory name ends with a newline). Wow. I love this!
- The remaining part is mostly the same as before. Still very sweet.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks for making me aware of locate, would find not be better when using with newly created files over locate?

Comment: @circular_logic of course, `find` will always find things! `locate` uses a database that is regularly updated, but, as you point out, not so often as to find newly created files.

Comment: typing go sends cd the path including the file name resulting in an error

Comment: @circular_logic Oh dear, you're so right! The guy who typed this is so dumb. Don't worry, I'm going to fix that for you in a second `:)`

Comment: @circular_logic How about this now? `:)`

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
findGO()
{
  TMP=$PWD
  PLACE=$(find . -iname $1 | egrep -o ".+\/")
  alias go="cd $TMP/${PLACE:2:${#PLACE}}"
  cd $PLACE
  echo "$TMP/${PLACE:2:${#PLACE}} now aliased to go"
}
```

This might help too: 
http://www.tecmint.com/35-practical-examples-of-linux-find-command/

Comment: This one will echo the full path placed into go, and is case insensitive.

Comment: try this again if you did - i forgot to add cd to the alias

Comment: thanks! but bash spits out: No such file or directory evry time go is use. is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: it works for me. i literally copy-pasted from my bash. Sorry. i forgot to re-init my bash, so i fudged it. Now try it. I checked and double-checked it this time.

Comment: wow. having a bad day. this post has been one of the more embarrassing. it's one foul-up after the next.

Comment: @Plasmarob Don't worry, I completely messed up my answer several times too `:)`. It happens!

Answer (score 0):

You were close, all you really needed for a crude version of your command was to escape or quote the space between `cd` and `$(...`. Here's a more filename-safe version:

```
foo () 
{ 
    alias go="cd '$(dirname "$(find . -name "$1" -print -quit)")'"
    echo "file directory containing $1 now aliased to go"
}
```

Some explanation, inside out:

```
[1] find . -name "$1" -print -quit
# Find the first file named by the argument, print it 
# and quit so we don't get too many files.

[2] dirname "$([1])"
# Execute the aforementioned command, capture its output, and 
# pass it as the argument to `dirname`. 
# `dirname` simply cuts off the end of the string from the 
# last / it finds through the end.

alias go="cd '$([2])'"
# Alias `go` to cd to the output of the previous command
# (directory containing first file found). 
# Put in quotes in case there are any funny characters. 
# Will break if there is a single quote in the name, but that can't be helped in bash.
```